# nslookup and awk get 2nd address

Tags: linux, kubernetes, awk, nslookup

I'm trying to get the address from the below result of my `nslookup`

Here I want to get is the 2nd address which is `10.0.45.45`

```sh
Server:         10.152.183.10
Address:        10.152.183.10#53

Name:   pg-master-0.pg-master-headless.postgres.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.1.45.45
```

Here is my code

```sh
MASTER_HOST=$(nslookup pg-master-0.pg-master-headlesss | awk '/^Address:/ {A=$2}; END {print A}');

echo $MASTER_HOST
```

Unfortunately, my output is:

```sh
10.152.183.10#53
```

Here I'm logged into the pod
[image]
then ran the nslookup that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 2nd "Address:" from the `nslookup` output, you can simply do:

```
awk '/^Address/{n++; if (n==2){print $2; exit}}'
```

Which checks if the line begins with `Address`, then increments a counter `n++` and when `n == 2` it outputs the second field and exits.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file called *nslookup.txt*, you would receive the following:

```
$ awk '/^Address/{n++; if (n==2){print $2; exit}}' nslookup.txt
10.1.45.45
```

Of course, using `nslookup` you would just pipe the output to `awk`. For example, if I wanted the IP of the machine *valkyrie* on my local subnet, I would use:

```
$ nslookup valkyrie | awk '/^Address/{n++; if (n==2){print $2; exit}}'
192.168.6.135
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I tried this ```MASTER_HOST=$(nslookup pg-master-0.pg-master-headlesss | awk '/^Address/{n++; if (n==2){print $2; exit}}');```
then output it ```echo $MASTER_HOST``` but it gave me blank result

Comment: Show me the full output of `nslookup pg-master-0.pg-master-headlesss` Add it to your question -- at the end. There is something different about the `nslookup` output. If you get blank output, that is because there is no 2nd `Address` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Hi David, I addd screenshot to the question. to show how i ran the ```nslookup```

Comment: No reason what is shown in the screenshot shouldn't have worked the same way? If there maybe whitespace before `"Address"`, you can change the regex to `/^\s*Address/` to handle that possibility. But I don't see whitespace with `nslookup` here.

Comment: The work around that i could think of is this 
```nslookup pg-master-0.pg-master-headless | awk 'FNR == 5 {print $2}'``` which gives me the 5th line and the second parameter that is the address i'm looking for however would like to check the possiblity if the return i get is really comes from ```Address```

Comment: Yes, you really need to anchor to `Address` at the beginning of the line. Another way would be `$1 ~ /Address/` as the check to verify the first field contains `"Address"`. Try `nslookup host | awk '$1~/Address/{n++; if (n==2){print $2; exit}}'` and see if that doesn't remedy things. You can add an `END` rule for some error checking `END {if (n<2) print "2nd Address not found"}`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `nslookup` cannot resolve `pg-master-0.pg-master-headlesss`. You might be running the operation from a different pod or from your personal server/machine which would have no idea of the services running in a cluster. (Your laptop doesn't use CoreDNS in your K8s cluster)

You can try running the script from the pod in your cluster and with the full FQDN to be safe:

```sh
$ kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -- bash
#
# apt update; apt -y install dnsutils # Installs dnslookup ...
# export MASTER_HOST=$(nslookup pg-master-0.pg-master-headless.postgres.svc.cluster.local | awk '/^Address:/ {A=$2}; END {print A}'); echo $MASTER_HOST"
```

Comment: i tried doing ```exec``` in my 2nd pod then tried ```nslookup``` and it gave me results
```Name:   pg-master-0.pg-master-headless.postgres.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.1.45.45```

Comment: based on my initial lookup i'm getting ```10.152.183.10#53``` which is not the actual ip but i think the server ip.. i need to get ```10.1.45.47``` which is the second address from my above command

Comment: hmm so you still have a problem or not? Did you try the awk script from the other answer?

Comment: yes i did.. so kind of ended up something like this 
```nslookup pg-master-0.pg-master-headless | awk 'FNR == 5 {print $2}'```
Not sure though if the ```Address``` i'm looking for is always on the 5th line. But this would suffice as of the moment.